# EJB injected to @Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, ejb

I am trying to inject EJB into spring @Controller (spring boot), each time I receive null pointer on stetelessBean.tt();

```
@Local
public interface IStetelessBean {
    void tt();
}

@Stateless
public class StetelesBean implements IStetelessBean {
    public void tt(){
        System.out.println("ttt");
    }
}

@Controller
public class PersonService {
    @EJB
    IStetelessBean stetelessBean;

    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public void test(){
        stetelessBean.tt();
    }
}
```

Any idea? I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can only inject beans, it knows about. By default, EJBs are not registered as Spring Beans. Also the `@EJB` annotation is not recognised by Spring. The only examples in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#ejb) use XML configuration, so far i could not find any example for Java configuration. You might be better off with changing your EJB into a Spring component, if that's possible.